# Open material nested mdDialog not working in safari

Tags: angular, angular-material2, mddialog

I am working on angular 4 project, In which, I have a requirement to open a dialog box over a dialog box. It works fine in all browsers like chrome and mozilla firefox but I doesn't work on safari.

I got a solution to close the parent dialog box and use setTimeOut function to open a second dialog box.

But my requirement is to not close the parent dialog box and open second dialog box over it.

If anybody know anything about it, Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncomment this line from polyfills.js

```
/** ALL Firefox browsers require the following to support `@angular/animation`. **/
import 'web-animations-js';  // <- Uncomment this line
```

and install

```
web-animations-js : 2.3.1
```

All works fine.